# How to test when "as" type casting is used in Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I am using Rhino mocks to unit test, and I have a statement like the below in my code

```
        Class1 message =
            msg as Class1;
        message.X="jdjk";
```

msg is of type Imsg and it is been mocked. How do I do type casting for a mocked object of msg so that I can stub X. Please help

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking due to the lack of code

Comment: instead of mocking interface Imsg, mock the concere class. MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();
Class1 c = mocks.StrictMock<Class1>();